# useContext returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-context

I am trying to use `creatContext/useContext` hooks to pass information throughout my App. I want to be able to see if a user has admin privileges without calling the API in every file and I keep getting this error in the Products.js file.
 `Line 5:27:  'AuthStatusContext' is not defined  no-undef`

This is what I have tried.

```js
// App.jsx
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
function App() {
  const AuthStatusContext = createContext();
  const [userHasAdminAccess, setUserHasAdminAccess] = useState(true);
  
  return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <AuthStatusContext.Provider value={userHasAdminAccess}>
            <Navbar />
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path='/cart' element={<Cart>} />
              <Route path='/products' element={<Products/>} />
             </Routes>
          </AuthStatusContext.Provider>
        </Router>
      </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

```js
// Products.jsx
import React, {useState,useEffect, useContext} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

function Products() {
// The line below is where the error occurs
  const userIsAdmin = useContext(AuthStatusContext);
    const [posts, setPosts]= useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        // unnecessary
      }, [])

  return (
   // some unnecessary code
}

export default Products;
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not define the context inside a component; put it in a separate file instead.

AuthStatusContext.js:

```js
import { createContext } from 'react';
const AuthStatusContext = createContext();
export default AuthStatusContext;
```

Then, import it in `App.jsx` and `Products.jsx` like so:

```
import AuthStatusContext from './AuthStatusContext.js';
```

The usage of the context is exactly the same as what you currently have.